# JavaScript - Enemies collide with each other

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem that has taken me a very long time to figure out. I made my enemies go straight at player and when circling enemies, they all go into one place so it looks like there is only one. Im trying to figure out how to make them not go inside each other but i do now know the maths I need for that.
This is my collision code:

```
for (var key in zombie){
  if (zombie[key].id == entity.id) continue;
  var collide = checkCollision(zombie[key],entity)
  if (collide){
    // Collision detected !
  }
}
```

Where checkCollision is a seperate function that checks for collisions. Thank you for help.

Comment: This is rather a logic then a programming problem. Take a paper and a pen, and youll find out the needed math very fast...

Comment: I know how collisions work, i just dont know what I need to make zombies do when they collide (make them not go into each other).

Comment: You didn't help, you just said "do it yourself".

Comment: Make a function that terminates zombie[key].id

Comment: That will break my game,

Comment: Why? That makes no sense. I have a question that encompasses this one. It terminates and adds shapes effeciently. Just set the zombie to undefined, and reuse the id with some other zombie.

Comment: I think you dont understand what I want. I just want the zombies to not collide with each other, something like crowd physics, where the entities never touch each other, or atleast never go inside each other.